# Online mods for minecraft servers help

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What happens to the other players if I run a minecraft server,have a mod (Team Fortress 2 dispenser mod) and use it? Can they use it or do they see anything? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Bukkit servers use plugins which you can install and all user joining with a vanilla client can play and utilize the plugin. If you use a Vanilla server provided by Mojang, you can install mods the same way you would do to your client. But any user joining must use the client version of the mod to join the server and utilize the mod.

Answer (score 1):

You will get an error saying that the block id does not exist. Th server needs the mod installed and the players playing on it.

Answer (score 0):

Its impossible to join a server that contains mods with a vanilla client. Both client and server needs the mod to be able to play.